# Storing Dates In SQL: Having Some Trouble

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a bunch of data sitting in a Postgres database for a website I am building. Problem is, I don't really know what I should do with the date information. For example, I have a table called `events` that has a date column that stores date information as a string until I can figure out what to do with it.

The reason they are in string format is unfortunately for the topic of my website, their is not a good API, so I had to scrape data. Here's what some of the data looks like inside the column:

```
|               Date                  |
|-------------------------------------|  
| Friday 07.30.2021 at 08:30 AM ET    |
| Wednesday 04.07.2021 at 10:00 PM ET |
| Saturday 03.27.2010                 |
| Monday 01.11.2010                   |
| Saturday 02.09.2019 at 05:00 PM ET  |
| Wednesday 03.31.2010                |
```

It would have been nice to have every row have the time with it, but a lot of entries don't. I have no problem doing some string manipulation on the data to get them into a certain format where they can be turned into a date, I am just somewhat stumped on what I should do next.

What would you do in this situation if you were restricted to the data seen in the events table? Would you store it as UTC? How would you handle the dates without a time? Would you give up and just display everything as EST dates regardless of where the user lives (lol)?

It would be nice to use these dates to display correctly for anyone anywhere in the world, but it looks like I might be pigeonholed because of the dates that don't have a time associated with them.

Comment: The dates can be handled: `select to_date('Wednesday 03.31.2010', 'day MM.DD.YYYY')::timestamptz; 2010-03-31 00:00:00-07`. I would store in `timestamptz` field. That rotates the timestamps to UTC for storage. You will have to decide what to do for dates without a time zone.

Comment: Yeah, I am unsure what to do with those. I'd still like to show a date for every event on the front end.

Comment: You can 'truncate' a `timestamp` to a `date`: `select '2010-03-31 00:00:00-07'::date; 2010-03-31`. Spend some time here [Date/times](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-datetime.html), [Date/time functions/operators](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-datetime.html) and [Data type formatting](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-formatting.html).

Answer (score 1):

Converting your mishmash free form looking date to a standard timestamp is not all that daunting as it seems. Your samples indicate you have a string with 5 separate pieces of information: day name, date (mm.dd.yyyy), literal (at),time of day, day part (AM,PM) and some code for timezone each separated by spaces. But for them to be useful the first step is splitting this into the individual parts. For that us a regular expression to ensure single spaces then use string_to_array to create an array of up to 6 elements. This gives:

```
+--------------------------+--------+----------------------------------+
|   Field                  | Array  | Action /                         |
|                          | index  | Usage                            |
+--------------------------+--------+----------------------------------+
|   day name               |   1    | ignore                           |
|   date                   |   2    | cast to date                     |
|   literal 'at'           |   3    | ignore                           |
|   time of day            |   4    | interval as hours since midnight |
|   AM/PM                  |   5    | adjustment for time of day       |
|   some code for timezone |   6    | ???                              |
+--------------------------+--------+----------------------------------+
```

Putting it all together we arrive at:

```
with test_data ( stg ) as 
     ( values ('Friday      07.30.2021 at     08:30 AM     ET'  )
            , ('Wednesday 04.07.2021 at 10:00 PM ET') 
            , ('Saturday 03.27.2010'                )
            , ('Monday 01.11.2010'                  )
            , ('Saturday 02.09.2019 at 05:00 PM ET' )
            , ('Wednesday 03.31.2010')
     ) 
   -- <<< Your query begins here >>>  
   , stg_array( strings) as 
     ( select string_to_array(regexp_replace(stg, '( ){1,}',' ','g'), ' ' )
         from test_data     --<<< your actual table  >>>     
     ) -- select * from stg_array 
   , as_columns( dt, tod_interval, adj_interval, tz) as
     ( select strings[2]::date 
            , case when array_length(strings,1) >= 4 
                        then strings[4]::interval
                        else '00:00':: interval 
              end
            , case when array_length(strings,1) >= 5 then 
                        case when strings[5]='PM' 
                             then interval '12 hours' 
                             else interval '0 hours' 
                        end
                   else interval '0 hours' 
              end
            , case when array_length(strings,1) >= 6 
                        then strings[6] 
                        else current_setting('TIMEZONE') 
              end 
         from stg_array
     ) 
select dt + tod_interval + adj_interval dtts, tz 
  from as_columns;
```

This gives the corresponding timestamp for date, time, and AM/PM indicator (in the current timezone) for items without a timezone specifies. For those containing a timezone code, you will have to convert to a proper timezone name. Note ET is not a valid timezone name nor a valid abbreviation. Perhaps a lookup table. See [example here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=5787dc252bf610584b98050582baa959); it also contains a regexp based solution. Also the example in run on `db<>fiddle`. Their server is in the UK, thus the timezone.